# MATLAB runtime javaclass not found

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB script where I open a serial port like this:

```
hnd = serial(obj.portName,'Baudrate',57600);
```

This works fine when running from MATLAB command prompt.

However, if I compile the script, then I face the following error message:

> Error using serial (line 120)
>   Cannot create: No class com.mathworks.toolbox.instrument.SerialComm can be located on the Java class path

Any ideas how to solve this issue?
I checked that the portname is correct (COM15).

Answer (score 0):

When you run from MATLAB there may be .jar libraries that get used (that are included on your java class path within MATLAB). 
However, when compiled, these may be missing.

If you are using the MATLAB Compiler to create the compiled script, there is a section to "Add additional files" (or something similer) which is where the .jar would be added as well as any other dependencies.

Try this:

1) Type 'javaclasspath' from MATLAB command prompt to display location of .jar libraries.

2) Locate the one required (this might be the hardest part!)

3) When compiling, make sure to specify this file(s).